# Install Nagios plugins - missing install instructional step?

Tags: plugins, ssh, nagios, nagiosxi

I have Nagios XI installed and want to monitor remote Redhat machine using SSH. Installing the agent is likely not allowed in our environment.

This is from [Nagios instruction](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Monitoring_Hosts_Using_SSH.pdf) from the page 2

Before you can use the check_by_ssh plugin, you must install/configure the following on the remote Linux/Unix server you want to
monitor:

● Create a nagios user
● Install Nagios plugins and/or monitoring scripts
● Install and configure the SSH daemon

I downloaded the Nagios official plugins(I believe there are 50 plugins) and extracted the files, but there is no instructional step for install command. I read the README file, but this seems to give me the steps of making the install files from the source, I think.

Is there a simple command that will run the install in order for me to install the plugins that will include `check_by_ssh` plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given by Nagios support team:

Nagios Plugin Installation

```
cd /tmp/nagios-plugins-2.1.2 
./configure --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios
make
make install
```